# How do we know that sound travels in waves?

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, acoustics, history

Most of the time we talk about sound travelling in waves. But what experiment was done is early days to conclude that sound travels in waves?

Comment: Should this question not migrate to "History of Science and Mathematics"? https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search on "history of the physics of sound:

> [One of the first discoveries](http://science.howstuffworks.com/sound-info5.htm) regarding sound was made in the sixth century B.C. by the Greek mathematician and philosopher Pythagoras. He noted the relationship between the length of a vibrating string and the tone it produces—what is now known as the first law of strings. Pythagoras may also have understood that the sensation of sound is caused by vibrations. Not long after his time it was recognized that this sensation depends on vibrations traveling through the air and striking the eardrum.
>
> [The history of sound](http://www.electricalfacts.com/Neca/Science/sound/history.shtml) is intrinsically linked to the history of waves. One of the first references of sound as a wave is found in a statement made by Aristotle when he indicated that air motion is generated by a source, trusting forward so that the sound travels unaltered in quality as far as the disturbance in the air manages to reach. Galileo is another one of the greatest contributor to our understanding of sound. He demonstrated that the frequency of sound waves determined the pitch. This was done by scraping a chisel across a brass plate producing a screech. Galileo then related the spacing of the grooves induced by the chisel to the pitch of the screech.
>
> Marin Mersenne was the first to measure the speed on sound on the air in 1640 by measuring of return of an echo. His determination of the speed of sound was in error by less than 10%. This is a remarkable achievement considering the technology at the time